# How to attach a value index from one list to another?

Tags: python

I'm a starting python user, and I need some help with this small problem of mine.
Basically I'm trying to create a program for myself to help me learn german.
I have a list of german words and a list of their translations.
I have already set it up so it would randomize each word, and my problem is with the translation.
I want the program to attach a value from the german word list to its translation.
Example:

> German = [ich, wir, gut]
>
> Translation = [we, good, I]

So when it would print the german word, it would know which of the translation is the right one.

I've tried to do it with the equal to operator but it doesnt seem to work at all:

```
import random

s = input("Press any key")

q = ["zeichnen", 'luft', ]

w = ['to start', "air"]

q = random.choice(q)

while True:

    print('Your german word: ', q)

    answer = input("Translation:")

    a = input('Try again?')

    if q == w:
            print('Youre right')
    else:
            print('Thats incorrect')

    if a == ('no') :
        break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my understanding, you want to get a random German word then the translation for that.
Unless the computer understands German, you cannot mix up the German word list.
Here is an alternative to your program:

```
from random import randint


q = ["zeichnen", 'luft']
w = ['to start', "air"]

while True:
    place = randint(0, len(q) - 1)

    print('Your german word:', q[place])

    answer = input("Translation: ")

    if answer == w[place]:
        print("You're right")
    else:
        print('Thats incorrect')

    a = input("Try again? ")

    if a == ('no') :
        break
```

The first line,

```
from random import randint
```

is another way to import a function instead of the whole module.

Also, the function of

```
place = randint(0, len(q) - 1)
```

is to get a random position from 0 to the position of the last item in the list.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `if answer == q` for your comparison.

Generally, if you use longer, more descriptive names for your variables then the code will be a bit easier to understand.

---

Also, welcome to Stack Overflow! For future questions, bear in mind that just saying "it doesn't work" is likely to get a question downvoted or closed; instead, try to say exactly what happens, and what you expected to happen instead.